# Sort list by LocalDate descending and LocalTime ascending

Tags: java, list, sorting, date, comparator

I have a list of objects that have a `LocalDateTime` field.
I want to sort all these objects very *specially* per date and time.

I explain how it should be done :

*Sort by Date Descending **BUT** by Time Ascending*

Here is an example :

Non sorted `LocalDateTime` :

- 2016-10-06T09:10
- 2016-10-06T10:34
- 2016-12-06T11:15
- 2016-11-06T10:34
- 2016-12-06T10:10
- 2016-12-06T06:56

Should be sorted in this order :

1. 2016-12-06T06:56
2. 2016-12-06T10:10
3. 2016-12-06T11:15
4. 2016-11-06T10:34
5. 2016-10-06T09:10
6. 2016-10-06T10:34

Remember that I need to sort an object with a field, not a list of `LocalDateTime`, but a List of Object with a `LocalDateTime` field.

Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Write a custom `Coparator` for this...

Comment: I would really like to provide a solution, but you haven't shown any effort, just requirements... Could you please add anything you tried to solve this? There's an **I** in your last sentence sentence of the question (*Remember that **I** need to sort ...*) that points at you...

Comment: @OleV.V. I wrote an Answer using conventional syntax to solve this problem. I also tried using your lambda syntax approach, but could not get it to work. Perhaps you care to give it a go yourself with a working examples. I am curious to see it in action.

Comment: Note the following, which appears on this Web page: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) (1)  Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. (2) Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation.

Comment: @OleV.V. Well I managed to get a variation of your code working. Is there a shorter or better way?

Comment: @OleV.V. I misread the problem statement. I was thinking of date-ascending and time-descending, so I thought your commented code was failing. I see now my code is wrong, as the Question asks for date-descending and time-ascending. I'll have to fix my Answer another time. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks a lot that exactly what I was looking for, didn't know about the comparator.thenComparing, that's why I couldn't get my list sorted like that

Comment: And @BasilBourque, I believe that you are quite correct: for the sorting that you were after, the modern comparator is necessarily that bit more complicated. I don’t think your code could be improved while maintaining the sort order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) objects know how to sort themselves chronologically. Your desire to sort by date descending (reverse chronological, later dates come first) yet also sort secondarily by time-of-day ascending (chronological) means the built-in functionality of the class’ implementation of [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#compareTo(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime)) method (required by the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface) cannot do the job.

## Conventional syntax

For custom sorting, write your own [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) implementation. That interface requires one method be implemented: [`compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)).

The logic here is simple:

- Compare the date portions.

  - If the two dates differ, reverse sort on that basis, and move on down the list.
  - If the same date on both, then dig deeper to compare their time-of-day portions, sorting chronologically.

Code.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class LocalDateTimeComparator implements Comparator < LocalDateTime >
{
    @Override
    public int compare ( LocalDateTime o1 , LocalDateTime o2 )
    {
        // Compare the date portion first. If equal, then look at time-of-day.
        int result = o1.toLocalDate().compareTo( o2.toLocalDate() ); // Consider only the date portion first.
        result = ( ( - 1 ) * result ); // Flip the positive/negative sign of the int, to get ascending order. Or more simply: `= - result ;`.
        if ( 0 == result ) // If dates are equal, look at the time-of-day.
        {
            System.out.println( "reversing " );
            result = o1.toLocalTime().compareTo( o2.toLocalTime() );
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Try out your example data with this comparator.

```
List < LocalDateTime > ldts = List.of(
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-10-06T09:10" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-10-06T10:34" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-06T11:15" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-11-06T10:34" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-06T10:10" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-06T06:56" )
);

List < LocalDateTime > sorted = new ArrayList <>( ldts );
Comparator < LocalDateTime > comparator = new LocalDateTimeComparator();
sorted.sort(  comparator );
```

Dump to console. We see success. The dates are in order of the October, November, and December dates of 2016, while the time-of-day

```
System.out.println( "ldts = " + ldts );
System.out.println( "sorted = " + sorted );
```

> ldts = [2016-10-06T09:10, 2016-10-06T10:34, 2016-12-06T11:15, 2016-11-06T10:34, 2016-12-06T10:10, 2016-12-06T06:56]
>
> sorted = [2016-12-06T06:56, 2016-12-06T10:10, 2016-12-06T11:15, 2016-11-06T10:34, 2016-10-06T09:10, 2016-10-06T10:34]

## Lambda syntax

The [comment by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62392699/sort-list-by-localdate-descending-and-localtime-ascending#comment110349070_62392699) shows how do do the equivalent work using functional lambda syntax in modern Java. That comment inspired me to try the functional approach.

The idea here is to use two `Comparator` objects: one for the date, and one for the time-of-day. We can nest one `Comparator` within another, in effect, by calling `Comparator::thenComparing`. So we need to establish both comparators, then feed one to the other. We instantiate a `comparatorDate`, then feed that one a `comparatorTime`, to get a `comparatorDateThenTime`. We pass `comparatorDateThenTime` to the `sort` method to actually get the sorting work performed.

```
List < LocalDateTime > ldts = List.of(
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-10-06T09:10" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-10-06T10:34" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-06T11:15" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-11-06T10:34" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-06T10:10" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-06T06:56" )
);

List < LocalDateTime > sorted = new ArrayList <>( ldts );

Comparator < LocalDateTime > comparatorDate =
        Comparator
                .comparing( ( LocalDateTime ldt ) -> ldt.toLocalDate() )
                .reversed();

Comparator < LocalDateTime > comparatorTime =
        Comparator
                .comparing( ( LocalDateTime ldt ) -> ldt.toLocalTime() );

Comparator < LocalDateTime > comparatorDateThenTime =
        comparatorDate
                .thenComparing(
                        comparatorTime
                );

sorted.sort( comparatorDateThenTime );

// Dump to console.
System.out.println( "ldts = " + ldts );
System.out.println( "sorted = " + sorted );
```

> ldts = [2016-10-06T09:10, 2016-10-06T10:34, 2016-12-06T11:15, 2016-11-06T10:34, 2016-12-06T10:10, 2016-12-06T06:56]
>
> sorted = [2016-12-06T06:56, 2016-12-06T10:10, 2016-12-06T11:15, 2016-11-06T10:34, 2016-10-06T09:10, 2016-10-06T10:34]

We can pull that all together using a one-liner using anonymous `Comparator` objects returned from calls to `Comparator.comparing` and `Comparator.reversed`.

```
List < LocalDateTime > ldts = List.of(
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-10-06T09:10" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-10-06T10:34" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-06T11:15" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-11-06T10:34" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-06T10:10" ) ,
        LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-06T06:56" )
);

List < LocalDateTime > sorted = new ArrayList <>( ldts );

sorted.sort(
        Comparator
                .comparing( ( LocalDateTime ldt ) -> ldt.toLocalDate() )
                .reversed()
                .thenComparing(
                        Comparator
                                .comparing( ( LocalDateTime ldt ) -> ldt.toLocalTime() )
                )

);

// Dump to console.
System.out.println( "ldts = " + ldts );
System.out.println( "sorted = " + sorted );
```

> ldts = [2016-10-06T09:10, 2016-10-06T10:34, 2016-12-06T11:15, 2016-11-06T10:34, 2016-12-06T10:10, 2016-12-06T06:56]
>
> sorted = [2016-12-06T06:56, 2016-12-06T10:10, 2016-12-06T11:15, 2016-11-06T10:34, 2016-10-06T09:10, 2016-10-06T10:34]

I think I would prefer to see the first one, the multi-line one, in production code. But I am not sure.

The real problem stated in the Question involves a `LocalDateTime` as a member field of another class. So let's expand our solution to include that nesting class. Here we invent a `Happening` class consisting of a description string with a `LocalDateTime` object.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Happening
{
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

    public Happening ( String description , LocalDateTime localDateTime )
    {
        this.description = Objects.requireNonNull( description );
        this.localDateTime = Objects.requireNonNull( localDateTime );
    }

    public String getDescription ( ) { return this.description; }

    public LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime ( ) { return this.localDateTime; }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Happening{ " +
                "description='" + description + '\'' +
                " | localDateTime=" + localDateTime +
                " }";
    }
}
```

Let's make a collection of those objects, and sort using code similar to that seen above. We must go one extra step, extracting a `LocalDateTime` object from within each `Happening` object.

```
List < Happening > happenings = List.of(
        new Happening( "aaa" , LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-10-06T09:10" ) ) ,
        new Happening( "bbb" , LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-10-06T10:34" ) ) ,
        new Happening( "ccc" , LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-06T11:15" ) ) ,
        new Happening( "ddd" , LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-11-06T10:34" ) ) ,
        new Happening( "eee" , LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-06T10:10" ) ) ,
        new Happening( "fff" , LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-06T06:56" ) )
);

List < Happening > sorted = new ArrayList <>( happenings );

sorted.sort(
        Comparator
                .comparing( ( Happening happening ) -> happening.getLocalDateTime().toLocalDate() )
                .reversed()
                .thenComparing(
                        Comparator
                                .comparing( ( Happening happening ) -> happening.getLocalDateTime().toLocalTime() )
                )

);

// Dump to console.
System.out.println( "happenings = " + happenings );
System.out.println( "sorted = " + sorted );
```

When run we go from a-b-c-d-e-f to f-e-c-d-a-b order.

> happenings = [Happening{ description='aaa' | localDateTime=2016-10-06T09:10 }, Happening{ description='bbb' | localDateTime=2016-10-06T10:34 }, Happening{ description='ccc' | localDateTime=2016-12-06T11:15 }, Happening{ description='ddd' | localDateTime=2016-11-06T10:34 }, Happening{ description='eee' | localDateTime=2016-12-06T10:10 }, Happening{ description='fff' | localDateTime=2016-12-06T06:56 }]
>
> sorted = [Happening{ description='fff' | localDateTime=2016-12-06T06:56 }, Happening{ description='eee' | localDateTime=2016-12-06T10:10 }, Happening{ description='ccc' | localDateTime=2016-12-06T11:15 }, Happening{ description='ddd' | localDateTime=2016-11-06T10:34 }, Happening{ description='aaa' | localDateTime=2016-10-06T09:10 }, Happening{ description='bbb' | localDateTime=2016-10-06T10:34 }]